# jQuery FileUpload registering multiple times

Tags: jquery, file, upload, blueimp

I'm working on a pretty old VB.NET ASP.NET website and trying to wire up drag and drop upload as well as "browse" functionality.  Everything works if you just go to the page and upload.  However, if you do any activities within the UpdatePanel on the page the functionality breaks.  So, I added this in my Page_Load:

```
 ' register the script that wires up the upload region
        Dim cstext1 As String = "setupFileUpload();"
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(upfiles, upfiles.GetType(), "UploadFileSetup", cstext1, True)
```

That works but the problem is that if you run multiple operations the fileupload seems to keep registering its behavior.  So then if I upload a file it shows up multiple times (example - 5 file uploads happen in the background.

My javascript looks something like this.  Any suggestions on how I can check to see if the handler is already registered?

snippet:

```
function setupFileUpload() {
        if ($('#fileupload').fileupload) return;

        $('#fileupload').fileupload({
            dataType: 'json',
            url: '<%= ResolveUrl("AjaxFileUpload.ashx") %>',
            add: function (e, data) {
                $('#<%= lblErrorFileType.ClientID %>').css('display', 'none');
                var valid = true;
                var re = /^.+\.((txt)|(jpeg)|(jpg)|(png)|(gif)|(pdf)|(doc)|(docx)|(xls)|(xlsx))$/i;
                $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
                    if (!re.test(file.name)) {
                        $('#<%= lblErrorFileType.ClientID %>').css('display', '');
                        valid = false;
                    }
                });

                if (valid)...
```

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned that the line with if ($('#fileupload').fileupload) return; was an attempt to avoid multiple registration but it seems to break everything in the case that the updatepanel posts back.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So after trying a few things, I added this call to Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager, which seems to work much better than passing the function name in the code-behind.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(setupFileUpload);
            $('#<%= lblErrorFileType.ClientID %>').css('display', 'none');
            setupFileUpload();
        });
```